# При get-запросе с параметром возвращается пустой объект

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Так обрабатываю запрос:

```js
router.get('/account/:id', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        res.send(req.query)
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            msg: "Непредвиденная ошибка, попробуйте снова"
        });
    }
});
```

Вот попытка запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё пробовал делать запрос на такой адрес:

```
http://localhost:5500/api/auth/account/:22334
```

Но тут уже явное нарушение синтаксиса.

Как решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Для работы с параметрами `route/:id` - используйте [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)
- Для работы со строкой запроса `route?page=1&limit=2` - используйте [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

```
router.get('/account/:id', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        res.send(req.params) // { id: ... }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            msg: "Непредвиденная ошибка, попробуйте снова"
        });
    }
});
```